# How to create curved (left or right)-arrow using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using [`matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow) to draw arrow between points. By changing 
`*shape*: ['full', 'left', 'right']`, I can create full, left or right-shaped arrow.

Now instead of straight arrows, I want to join points by curve arrows. The class [`matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow) does it, however, the arrow shape is always full. Is there any way to get 'left' or 'right' curved-arrows in matplotlib?

The arrows should look like [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/arrow_demo.png), however I want them to be curved instead of straight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need:

```
set_connectionstyle("arc,angleA=0,armA=30,rad=10")
```

together with

```
set_arrowstyle("Fancy,head_length=0.2")
```

Comment: All the arrowstyle create full arrows instead of half (left, right) arrows.